# Access issue with findMeetingTimes API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

When tried accessing the findMeetingTimes API, I get this following error.

[image: Access Denied Error]

Given a userID or userprincipalname, can we access the findMeetingTimes api to find the meeting time availability of that particular user, along with the meeting room suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing to grant the following permissions:

**1) Calendars.Read.Shared 
  2) Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared**

ref: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_findmeetingtimes

suggestion: better if you can check your task with graph explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) so that you don't need to add authorization bearer and permission scopes.

Comment: Thanks @Gopal Zadafiya , With the Graph Explorer I could test with my own data. However I would like to use this API independent of the logged in user ( say, with the admin consent). And the context is, I am trying to build a bot that could let people know on the availability of attendees & the meeting room.